# How do I update software that was built from source?

Tags: compiling, upgrade, nginx, software-updates

If I [build NGINX from source](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html), how do I update it?

I'm on a Debian machine and used to install and update software on the CLI with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A package manager installs the binaries and configuration files that were compiled by the package maintainer (and performs many other functions as well). But, if you build from source, then you are responsible for rebuilding from source again - for each and every upgrade instance, possibly including its dependencies as well, if those were compiled from source.